# jQuery map cells in table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table with a rather simple structure each row is formatted like so:

```
<tr>
    <td>some text</td>
    <td><input value="somevalue"></td>
    <td><input value="somevalue"></td>
    <td><input value="somevalue"></td>
    <td>
        <select>
            <option>some option</option>
            <option>some option</option>
            <option>some option</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I would like to find a way to get the values for each input and the selected value for the select and place them in an array. what is the correct way to get that info? I have tried

```
$('td').each(function(){
    $(this).find('input').val();//Only returns the first input value
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the aptly named [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) method to build arrays from the results of a function called on each element:

```
$("tr").each(function() {
    var rowValues = $("input, select", this).map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();

    // Do something with `rowValues`...
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. I had read over the .map function on the jquery site, I always find it frustrating that people cant seem to give an example with no fluff. Its like they show the .map function combined with 10 other (and IMHO completely unnecessary) functions that you kinda get lost as to which part is doing what. So I couldn't really figure out what I was seeing. So thanks again for the simple yet very helpful response :)